# Webapp not displaying properly on ipad air

Tags: ios, css, html, ipad

Im having a problem with a webapp I have developed. I would really appreciate your help and guidance with this issue.

My app has been developed at 1024px x 768px and it is working fine on the ipad 4th gen. Please note that this app is made for landscape mode only.

When the app is viewed on ipad air it seems to disappear slightly off the screen bottom and right. I have checked the resolutions and they seem to be both the same.

Does anyone know why this is caused?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you show us some example i.e a screenshot or link to the web app ?

Comment: Hi there, Thank you very much for your comment. Unfortuantly the app is hosted on secure server for internal use only. And I cant share any screenshots. What I can see on the screen though is below:

4th gen: fits perfectly to the screen

ipad air: app is bigger than the screen by about 100px

Thanks again in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally managed to find an answer! - This problem was oocuring due to now devlaring the viewport in the meta tag header! Once decalred the problem sorted!